# Unable to initiate customer conversation with WhatsappSender using Twilio API

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I've set up a WhatsApp sender, but I can't seem to be able to initiate a customer conversation (I am using an approved template. When I check `Programmable Messaging Logs` I see that my messages are erroring out with a `30001 Queue overflow` error and they seem to  enqueue-->dequeue-->enqueue-->ect.

I've tried initiating a customer conversation programmatically via the Twilio API - I was expecting my message to be delivered, but it was not.

I want to be able to send messages from this number and not use the sandbox. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Queue/Dequeue screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this is happening, but I think more info may be needed to figure out exactly what is happening. There are a bunch of things that could be causing this, but its hard to diagnose from here:

- Are you using a Toll Free number that is not [verified](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/5377174717595-Toll-Free-Message-Verification-for-US-Canada)?
- Are you following the right format for your [whatsapp template](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-whatsapp-notification-messages-templates)?
- Has your whatsapp sender finished going through the [approval process](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/self-sign-up)?

It sounds like you have already done a lot of these, so you could try reaching out to [Twilio support](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us). They can look into your account and possibly give you an answer with more context.